# How apt-get selects from a list of alternative dependencies?

Tags: apt, dependencies, deb

I understand that in the Depends: section of the deb control files, a package may specify alternative dependencies separated by `|` symbol to satisfy a single dependency.

My question is, how does `apt-get` decides which one to install when there are alternatives?

Is there a way to manually alter this selection using something similar to `apt_preferences`?

For example, if a package depends on java and in the Depends section we have `openjdk-6-jre | sun-java6-jre`, how can I force apt-get to install `openjdk-6-jre` provided that the system does not have either packages installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Debian Policy Manual, Chapter 7 - Declaring relationships between packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) you can read

> In the Depends, Recommends, Suggests, Pre-Depends, Build-Depends and
>   Build-Depends-Indep control fields of the package, which declare
>   dependencies on other packages, the package names listed may also
>   include lists of alternative package names, separated by vertical bar
>   (pipe) symbols |. In such a case, if any one of the alternative
>   packages is installed, that part of the dependency is considered to be
>   satisfied.

I cannot find any other useful information about *list of alternatives* in the whole document, so I should conclude that, in case none of the packages in the list is already installed, the first one in the list would be chosen. But be aware that this is only my interpretation.

Comment: In output of `apt-cache depends` pipe character is the prefix denoting that the package on that line and the one on the next line are alternatives.