# How can I determine why apt-get will install a package?

Tags: dependencies

This question is similar to [How can I find out why a package was installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4502/how-can-i-find-out-why-a-package-was-installed), but in my case I'd like to know *before* actually installing a package, why it will install a particular dependency.

So for example I might run

```
sudo apt-get install superfoo
```

and the output will say something like:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foo bar baz ... libderp libjunk
```

And this might be a really huge list. In some instances I'll see something that is going to be installed that doesn't really make sense to me given what I'm installing, so I want to know *why* that particular dependency is going to be installed.

In the above example let's say I'd like to understand why `libderp` would get installed. I know that somehow there is a chain of dependencies between `superfoo` and `libderp` but the huge list of packages to be installed makes it hard to see what this chain is.

Once I know the dependency chain, I can decide whether I really want to install the original package or not, and/or whether I should get in touch with the maintainer of that package to see if they *really* need to have those dependencies there.

Comment: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 22):

`apt-rdepends` does this, *without* installing 50+ libraries of cruft like `ubuntu-dev-tools`.

```
durr@scraper:~$ apt-rdepends mercurial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mercurial
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: mercurial-common (= 2.8.2-1ubuntu1)
  Depends: python (<< 2.8)
  Depends: ucf (>= 2.0020)
libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
gcc-4.9-base
multiarch-support
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2)
mercurial-common
  Depends: python (<< 2.8)
  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
python
  Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3)
  Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3)
  Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.5-1~)
libpython-stdlib
  Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (>= 2.7.5-1~)
libpython2.7-stdlib
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libexpat1 (>= 2.1~beta3)
  Depends: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4)
  Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 5.6+20070908)
  Depends: libpython2.7-minimal (= 2.7.6-8)
  Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9)
  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Depends: mime-support
libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libdb5.3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libexpat1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libffi6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libncursesw5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libtinfo5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libpython2.7-minimal
libreadline6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Depends: readline-common
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
readline-common
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
  Depends: install-info
dpkg
  PreDepends: libbz2-1.0
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 2.1.0)
  PreDepends: tar (>= 1.23)
  PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
liblzma5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libselinux1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libpcre3
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libpcre3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
tar
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
libacl1
  Depends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libattr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
zlib1g
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
install-info
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1)
libsqlite3-0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libssl1.0.0
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
debconf
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4)
perl-base
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.20)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
debconf-2.0
mime-support
python-minimal
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.13.20)
  Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.5-1~)
python2.7-minimal
  Depends: libpython2.7-minimal (= 2.7.6-8)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
python2.7
  Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.6-8)
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.6-8)
python:any
ucf
  Depends: coreutils (>= 5.91)
  Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.19)
coreutils
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8)
  PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
```

On my clean ubuntu server install, `apt-rdepends` only required `libapt-pkg-perl` for installation. It's much lighter then `ubuntu-dev-tools`, and yet is still recursive, so you get *all* the dependencies, rather then just the first-order dependencies, like `apt-cache depends` returns.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but I think apt-rdepends is not the same as reverse-depends. apt-rdepends lists the recursive dependencies of a package, while reverse-depends lists the packages that depend on the package given.

Comment: apt-rdepends -r lists the reverse dependencies.

Answer (score 19):

What you really seem to be asking is "How do I diagram dependencies?" so you can see which packages pull in which dependencies.

You get both text and diagrammed dependencies from the `apt-cache` command (included in the apt package, part of the default install).

Here's an example of apt-cache for listing dependencies of the 'hello' package in text format. Text output will always be only one level.

```
$ apt-cache depends hello
hello
  Depends: libc6
 |Depends: dpkg
  Depends: install-info
```

You can read the diagram using any dotfile viewer, such as `dotty` (included in the graphviz package, also part of the default install)

Here's an example of getting the full dependency tree in graphical format, then displaying it. Graphical output will always be the full tree.

```
$ apt-cache dotty hello > dotfile
$ dotty dotfile
```

Looking it over, you can see that the 'hello' package pulls in a ton of Perl packages...and which dependency does it.

Comment: While that would work, it would be some serious work to do it this way to see what was pulling in a certain package if the package was a dependency of a dependency.

Comment: Not at all. Merely look at the dotfile picture.

Comment: `apt-cache depends --recurse` will give you the full picture, but apt-rdepends below is better because it only follows actual dependencies, not recommended or suggested ones.

Comment: Although apt-get actually will install recommended dependencies unless you use the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

Comment: What does that bar mean? `|`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - I'm not certain, but going by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99601/how-apt-get-selects-from-a-list-of-alternative-dependencies) it *appears* to mean that the dependency is one of various alternatives.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - yes, check out the reverse depends of java-common and the forward depends of rssowl, as an example.  (apt-cache depends and apt-cache rdepends)

Comment: Even with `hello`, I can't get `dotty` to do anything other than crash.  (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @Diagon that's a different question. It works for us....

Answer (score 13):

One can use builtin APT debug options to get a sense of the underlying dependency tree from the resolver.

From `apt.conf(5)`

> Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall
>
> Generate debug messages describing which packages are being automatically installed to resolve dependencies. This corresponds to the initial auto-install pass performed in, e.g., apt-get install, and not to the full apt dependency resolver; see Debug::pkgProblemResolver for that.

```
$ apt install -s -o Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=true mercurial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
  Installing mercurial-common as Depends of mercurial
    Installing python2 as Depends of mercurial-common
      Installing python2-minimal as PreDepends of python2
        Installing python2.7-minimal as Depends of python2-minimal
          Installing libpython2.7-minimal as Depends of python2.7-minimal
      Installing python2.7 as Depends of python2
        Installing libpython2.7-stdlib as Depends of python2.7
      Installing libpython2-stdlib as Depends of python2
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib mercurial-common python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
```

Comment: This answer is the real one, don't know why did people down-vote it. Note that the quoted output goes to stderr, it's important if you are using grep for example

Comment: This is the only one which listed everything. Other tools don't list packages brought in because they are Recommended or installed through virtual packages/Provides. Thanks so much! Now to parse this and turn it into DOT...

Comment: @remram You're welcome. Note if you need dot output you might find [debtree](https://packages.debian.org/debtree) helpful

Comment: What if I already installed mercurial?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking! This is extra nice, since it does not need additional dependencies

Answer (score 8):

There may be an easier way to do this, but it can be done if you use reverse-depends. You will need to install the ubuntu-dev-tools package by doing

`apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools`

Or by clicking this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

Once installed, you can then use reverse-depends to see what depends on a specific package. For example, if you try to install something that wants to install a bunch of extra packages and you want to see why "libsmpeg0" is being installed, you run

```
reverse-depends libsmpeg0
```

Which would output the following.

```
Reverse-Recommends
==================
* sandboxgamemaker

Reverse-Depends
===============
* btanks
* fenix-plugin-mpeg [armel armhf i386 powerpc]
* fillets-ng
* gltron [amd64 armel i386 powerpc]
* libalien-sdl-perl
* libsdl-perl [i386]
* libsmpeg-dev
* libtaoframework-sdl1.2-cil
* python-pygame
* ruby-sdl
* sdlbrt
* smpeg-gtv
* smpeg-plaympeg
* tdfsb

Packages without architectures listed are reverse-dependencies in: amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
```

Take a look and see if the package you want to install is in that list. If not, then another one of the packages that is being pulled in during that initial install will show up in that list, and you will need to run reverse-depends on that package. Eventually you will see the initial package you want to install in that list. At that point, you should have a chain showing exactly why that package was installed.

As an added note, I believe recommends is on by default, so if something is set as a recommends it will get pulled in to. Suggests if off, but reverse-depends can show that info as well.

Comment: While I'm sure this answer would work, it personifies the issue the OP is trying to avoid. `ubuntu-dev-tools` results in the following packages being installed. `bzr bzr-builddeb dctrl-tools debian-archive-keyring debian-keyring debootstrap devscripts diffstat distro-info distro-info-data dput genisoimage
  gettext hardening-includes intltool-debian libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasprintf-dev libassuan0 libauthen-sasl-perl libautodie-perl
  libclone-perl libcommon-sense-perl libcroco3 libdigest-hmac-perl libdistro-info-perl libemail-valid-perl libencode-locale-perl liberror-perl`

Comment: [continued] `python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-oauth python-paramiko python-reportbug python-secretstorage python-simplejson
  python-soappy python-support python-wadllib python3-debian python3-magic quilt reportbug t1utils unzip wdiff xdelta`

(Note: The above was *just* the required packages from `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools` on a fairly clean ubuntu server instance).

If you're trying to *avoid* installing huge amounts of cruft, this is probably the worst solution possible.